# Variable in for loop not accessed by Pylance

Tags: python, for-loop, visual-studio-code, kivy, pylance

I'm making an application in python that can access an excel file to read and write data. Excel file has weekdays and user will be reading or writing the cell next to them. Below, I wrote some loops to check if user left some changes unsaved. And if the cell for a certain day has unsaved changes, label inside the app changes to point it out to the user.

Like: Monday --> Monday*

"kvlabel", for some reason stays in a darker color and hovering my mouse over it reveals that it's not accessed by Pylance. I changed it's name and position but it doesn't make a difference.

```
daytexts = [
    self.root.get_screen("weeklywin").ids.mon_text.text, 
    self.root.get_screen("weeklywin").ids.tue_text.text, 
    self.root.get_screen("weeklywin").ids.wed_text.text, 
    self.root.get_screen("weeklywin").ids.thu_text.text, 
    self.root.get_screen("weeklywin").ids.fri_text.text
    ]

cells = [e4, e10, e16, e22, e28]

daylabel = ["mon_label", "tue_label", "wed_label", "thu_label", "fri_label"]

daylabelkv = [
    self.root.get_screen("weeklywin").ids.mon_label.text, 
    self.root.get_screen("weeklywin").ids.tue_label.text, 
    self.root.get_screen("weeklywin").ids.wed_label.text, 
    self.root.get_screen("weeklywin").ids.thu_label.text, 
    self.root.get_screen("weeklywin").ids.fri_label.text
    ]

justday = ["Pazartesi", "Salı", "Çarşamba", "Perşembe", "Cuma"]

for day, cell, label in zip(daytexts, cells, daylabel):
    if day != cell and label not in self.excel_unsaved_label:
        self.excel_unsaved_label.append(label)
    elif day == cell and label in self.excel_unsaved_label:
        self.excel_unsaved_label.remove(label)
        
if self.excel_unsaved_label:
    self.show_excel_leave_warn()
    for label2, kvlabel, tehday in zip(daylabel, daylabelkv, justday):
        if label2 in self.excel_unsaved_label:
            kvlabel = tehday+"*"
        else:
            kvlabel = tehday
                    
else:
    self.root.current = caller
```

Comment: The line `kvlabel = tehday+"*"` has no effect on the object that `kvlabel` previously referred to (i.e. the element of `daylabelkv`).  Instead it reassigns the name `kvlabel` to point to a new value.  So your code will leave the values in `daylabelkv` unchanged - which is probably not what you want?

Comment: I'm trying to change the values of what's inside 'daylabelkv', yes. I'm not that knowledgeable in these stuff. Since 'daytexts' let me read texts using ids method in a list, I assumed ids in lists also would let me change the values. Do I have to use if-else statements for this instead of a for loop? I can't think of a better way right now.

Comment: don't change the iterable you loop over, you will get an exception, keep track of what you want to change and after the loop apply the changes. Loop variables have no binding with the iterator, they are the result of dereferencing the iterator

Comment: the variable `kvlabel` is **never** used

Comment: please update the indentation of you code, on lines with `[]` and `()` you may go to the next line with out problems, no need for these massive long lines

Comment: @mkfmtr one approach would be to loop using an index: `for i in range(len(daylabel))`.  Then you can modify elements of `daylabelkv` by accessing them as `daylabelkv[i]`.

Comment: Also, it might be cleaner if your `daylabelkv` contained the actual label objects rather than their `text` values: then you would modify them by doing something like `daylabelkv[i].text = tehday+"*"`.  (I don't know the library you're using so I can't say for sure this is exactly the right way to set the text.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @slothrop suggested, I removed `.text` from `daylabelkv`:

```
daylabelkv = [
    self.root.get_screen("weeklywin").ids.mon_label, 
    self.root.get_screen("weeklywin").ids.tue_label, 
    self.root.get_screen("weeklywin").ids.wed_label, 
    self.root.get_screen("weeklywin").ids.thu_label, 
    self.root.get_screen("weeklywin").ids.fri_label]
```

and changed the loop like this:

```
for label2, i, tehday in zip(daylabel, range(len(daylabelkv)), justday):
    if label2 in self.excel_unsaved_label:
        daylabelkv[i].text = tehday+"*"
```

It does what I want now. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Cool.  Actually, now you're working with the label objects directly, you could go back to `zip(daylabel, daylabelkv, justday)` without the index if you want.  That's because `label_obj.text = s` is an operation that changes `label_obj` directly, not one that reassigns a name.

Comment: Here's some background issue on what's behind the original problem and the fix: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html